# Starting axis label with subscript

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am trying to add specific labels to my axes in R. I have read numerous posts indicating to use the `expression` function and brackets to do this. The label I want to add to my axis starts and ends with a subscript.

```
plot(1:10, xlab=expression([10]'x'[5])
```

Starting the label with a subscript results in an error:

`Error: unexpected '[' in "plot(1:10, xlab=expression(["`

I have attempted to add in empty quotation marks as a form of placeholder, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to use as labels, and what do you want to use as superscripts?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? `plot(1:10, xlab=expression(phantom(1)[10]*x[5]))`. It's unclear what the desired result is.

Comment: I didn't think it was that unclear, but maybe I'm reading between the lines too much. <sub>10</sub>x<sub>5</sub> to crudely represent it in tags

Comment: "10" in subscript, "x" in normal script, and "5" in subscript. The answer below does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate multiple subscripts with an asterisk (`*`), and start the `expression` with an empty string

```
plot(1:10, xlab=expression(''[10]*'x'[5]))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to quote the `x` - `plot(1:10, xlab=expression(''[10]*x[5]))` should work